# How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying Firestore, and I'm stuck at something very simple: "updating an array (aka a subdocument)".

My DB structure is super simple. For example:

```
proprietary: "John Doe",
sharedWith:
  [
    {who: "first@test.com", when:timestamp},
    {who: "another@test.com", when:timestamp},
  ],
```

I'm trying (without success) to push new records into `shareWith` array of objects.

I've tried:

```
// With SET
firebase.firestore()
.collection('proprietary')
.doc(docID)
.set(
  { sharedWith: [{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() }] },
  { merge: true }
)

// With UPDATE
firebase.firestore()
.collection('proprietary')
.doc(docID)
.update({ sharedWith: [{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() }] })
```

None works. These queries overwrite my array.

The answer might be simple, but I could'nt find it...

Comment: Hey did you figure it out? I still can't find an answer.

Comment: For Android, is at simple as [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Edit 08/13/2018**: There is now support for native array operations in Cloud Firestore. See [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794212/324977) below.

---

There is currently no way to update a single array element (or add/remove a single element) in Cloud Firestore.

This code here:

```
firebase.firestore()
.collection('proprietary')
.doc(docID)
.set(
  { sharedWith: [{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() }] },
  { merge: true }
)
```

This says to set the document at `proprietary/docID` such that `sharedWith = [{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() }` but to not affect any existing document properties.  It's very similar to the `update()` call you provided however the `set()` call with create the document if it does not exist while the `update()` call will fail.

So you have two options to achieve what you want.

**Option 1 - Set the whole array**

Call `set()` with the entire contents of the array, which will require reading the current data from the DB first.  If you're concerned about concurrent updates you can do all of this in a transaction.

**Option 2 - Use a subcollection**

You could make `sharedWith` a subcollection of the main document. Then
adding a single item would look like this:

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection('proprietary')
  .doc(docID)
  .collection('sharedWith')
  .add({ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() })
```

Of course this comes with new limitations. You would not be able to query
documents based on who they are shared with, nor would you be able to
get the doc and all of the `sharedWith` data in a single operation.

Comment: This is so frustrating...but thanks for letting me know I'm not going crazy.

Comment: this is big drawback, Google has to fix it asap.

Comment: @DougGalante's answer indicates this has been fixed. Use the `arrayUnion` method.

Comment: Guy see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73427668/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore?noredirect=1#comment129679860_73427668 , this really frustrating me ,i still don't get it

Answer (score 226):

Firestore now has two functions that allow you to update an array without re-writing the entire thing.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data, specifically https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

> Update elements in an array
>
> If your document contains an array field, you can use `arrayUnion()` and
> `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements. `arrayUnion()` adds elements
> to an array but only elements not already present. `arrayRemove()`
> removes all instances of each given element.

Comment: Is there any way to update a specific index from the array?

Comment: How to use this array update feature with "react-native-firebase" ? (I cant find this on official docs of react-native-firebase)

Comment: @ArturCarvalho No, the reason why is explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s&feature=youtu.be&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&t=525

Comment: @ArturCarvalho have you find any solution for update a specific index from the array?

Comment: for who needs to do it on the client, use "import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';" then "firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(NEW_ELEMENT)"

Comment: Be great if there was a way to update an item in an array with a specific id.  Like an arrayUnion but with a merge: true.  At the moment it requires 2 operations to remove the array item and then add it again with the new data.

Answer (score 38):

Here is the latest example from the Firestore documentation:

*firebase.firestore.FieldValue.*[ArrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayunion)

```js
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

Comment: @nifCody, this will indeed add a new string element "greater_virginia" to an existing array "regions".  I have tested it successfully, and definitely not adding "object".  It is in sync with the question as stated: "push new records".

Answer (score 24):

You can use a transaction (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to get the array, push onto it and then update the document:

```
    const booking = { some: "data" };
    const userRef = this.db.collection("users").doc(userId);

    this.db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
        return transaction.get(userRef).then(doc => {
            if (!doc.data().bookings) {
                transaction.set({
                    bookings: [booking]
                });
            } else {
                const bookings = doc.data().bookings;
                bookings.push(booking);
                transaction.update(userRef, { bookings: bookings });
            }
        });
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: At if statement you should change it into this, because you are missing the `documentReference` add `userRef` as shown: 
`transaction.set(userRef, {
                    bookings: [booking]
                });`

Comment: This will re write the whole array

Answer (score 10):

Sorry Late to party but Firestore solved it way back in aug 2018 so If you still looking for that here it is all issues solved with regards to arrays.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html[Official blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)

array-contains, arrayRemove, arrayUnion for checking, removing and updating arrays. Hope it helps.

Comment: That link would have been useful if it had code associated with each example.

Answer (score 6):

To build on [Sam Stern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773121/6224698), there is also a **3rd option** which made things easier for me and that is using what Google call a Map, which is essentially a dictionary.

I think a dictionary is far better for the use case you're describing. I usually use arrays for stuff that isn't really updated too much, so they are more or less static. But for stuff that gets written a lot, specifically values that need to be updated for fields that are linked to something else in the database, dictionaries prove to be much easier to maintain and work with.

So for your specific case, the DB structure would look like this:

```
proprietary: "John Doe"
sharedWith:{
  whoEmail1: {when: timestamp},
  whoEmail2: {when: timestamp}
}
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
var whoEmail = 'first@test.com';

var sharedObject = {};
sharedObject['sharedWith.' + whoEmail + '.when'] = new Date();
sharedObject['merge'] = true;

firebase.firestore()
.collection('proprietary')
.doc(docID)
.update(sharedObject);
```

The reason for defining the object as a variable is that using `'sharedWith.' + whoEmail + '.when'` directly in the set method will result in an error, at least when using it in a Node.js cloud function.

Answer (score 5):

#Edit (add explanation :) )
say you have an array you want to update your existing firestore document field with. You can use `set(yourData, {merge: true} )` passing setOptions(second param in set function) with `{merge: true}` is must in order to merge the changes instead of overwriting. here is what the official documentation says about it

> An options object that configures the behavior of set() calls in DocumentReference, WriteBatch, and Transaction. These calls can be configured to perform granular merges instead of overwriting the target documents in their entirety by providing a SetOptions with merge: true.

you can use this

```
const yourNewArray = [{who: "first@test.com", when:timestamp}
{who: "another@test.com", when:timestamp}]    


collectionRef.doc(docId).set(
  {
    proprietary: "jhon",
    sharedWith: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...yourNewArray),
  },
  { merge: true },
);
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut yes you are right. I definitely accept the criticism for not adding an explanation for my answer.  I have edited my answer. hope it helps much better now.

Answer (score 3):

```
addToCart(docId: string, prodId: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.baseAngularFirestore.collection('carts').doc(docId).update({
        products:
        firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            productId: prodId,
            qty: 1
        }),
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.

Comment: Indeed, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

We can use `arrayUnion({})` method to achive this.

Try this:

```js
collectionRef.doc(ID).update({
    sharedWith: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
       who: "first@test.com",
       when: new Date()
    })
});
```

Documentation can find here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 3):

i know this is really old, but to help people newbies with the issue

firebase V9 provides a solution using the arrayUnion and arrayRemove

```
await updateDoc(documentRef, {
    proprietary: arrayUnion( { sharedWith: [{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() }] }
});
```

[check this out for more explanation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11)

Answer (score 2):

Other than the answers mentioned above. This will do it.
*Using Angular 5 and AngularFire2.* or use firebase.firestore() instead of this.afs

```
  // say you have have the following object and 
  // database structure as you mentioned in your post
  data = { who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() };

  ...othercode


  addSharedWith(data) {

    const postDocRef = this.afs.collection('posts').doc('docID');

    postDocRef.subscribe( post => {

      // Grab the existing sharedWith Array
      // If post.sharedWith doesn`t exsit initiated with empty array
      const foo = { 'sharedWith' : post.sharedWith || []};

      // Grab the existing sharedWith Array
      foo['sharedWith'].push(data);

      // pass updated to fireStore
      postsDocRef.update(foo);
      // using .set() will overwrite everything
      // .update will only update existing values, 
      // so we initiated sharedWith with empty array
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider John Doe a document rather than a collection

Give it a collection of things and thingsSharedWithOthers

Then you can map and query John Doe's shared things in that parallel thingsSharedWithOthers collection.

```
proprietary: "John Doe"(a document)

things(collection of John's things documents)

thingsSharedWithOthers(collection of John's things being shared with others):
[thingId]:
    {who: "first@test.com", when:timestamp}
    {who: "another@test.com", when:timestamp}

then set thingsSharedWithOthers

firebase.firestore()
.collection('thingsSharedWithOthers')
.set(
{ [thingId]:{ who: "third@test.com", when: new Date() } },
{ merge: true }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to Update an array in a firebase document.
You can do this.

```
    var documentRef = db.collection("Your collection name").doc("Your doc name")

    documentRef.update({
yourArrayName: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("The Value you want to enter")});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()` provides the solution for array update in firestore, at the same time it is required to use `{merge:true}`. If you do not use `{merge:true}` it will delete all other fields in the document while updating with the new value. Here is the working code for updating array without loosing data in the reference document with `.set()` method:

```js
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("your_collection_name").doc("your_doc_id");

docRef.set({yourArrayField: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("value_to_add")}, {merge:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the document contains a nested object in the form of an array, .dot notation can be used to reference and update nested fields.
Node.js example:

```
const users = {
  name: 'Tom',
  surname: 'Smith',
  favorites: {
    sport: 'tennis',
    color: 'red',
    subject: 'math'
  }
};

const update = await db.collection('users').doc('Tom').update({
  'favorites.sport': 'snowboard'
});
```

or Android sdk example:

```
db.collection("users").document("Tom")
        .update(
               'favorites.sport': 'snowboard'
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection("collection")
 .doc("docId")
 .update({arrayOfObj: fieldValue.arrayUnion({...item})})
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for Java firestore sdk solution to add items in array field:

```
List<String> list = java.util.Arrays.asList("A", "B");
Object[] fieldsToUpdate = list.toArray();
DocumentReference docRef = getCollection().document("docId");
docRef.update(fieldName, FieldValue.arrayUnion(fieldsToUpdate));
```

To delete items from array user: `FieldValue.arrayRemove()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple hack in firestore:

use path with "." as property name:

`propertyname.arraysubname.${id}`:

Comment: Where do you type this?