# How to add an object to an array + Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add an `Object` to an existing `Array` in firestore.
I already have one `Object` in the `Array`, now I want to add the second `Object`.

So I have created this code below to store data to firestore.
After I triggered the function the data in `firestore` won't add a new `Object` to the array

Code:

```
  let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`

  fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).update({
      userId: this.currentUser.uid,
      posts: [
        {
          createdOn: this.postDetails.createdOn,
          content: this.postDetails.content,
          image: this.postDetails.image,
          comments: this.postDetails.comments,
          likes: this.postDetails.likes,
          tags: this.model,
          userData: [

            { userName: this.userProfile.name,
              userId: this.currentUser.uid,
              userImage: this.userProfile.userImage
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794212/2305594

Answer (score 0):

Update doesn't automatically add a new object to array, the way you are doing it, you are simply overwriting the `posts` Array with a new object.

To add new object to existing array, you either read old array and then manipulate it your self, then write it back in using the transaction method or use the new array method as mentioned by @Joseph