# firebase retrieve a list of array without manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have to do bunch of ObjectKey and map just to render a list, why so much hassle, does firebase has built-in util for that?

```
onListenForMessages = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    this.props.firebase
      .messages()
      .orderByChild('createdAt')
      .limitToLast(this.state.limit)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        const messageObject = snapshot.val();

        if (messageObject) {
          const messageList = Object.keys(messageObject).map(key => ({
            ...messageObject[key],
            uid: key,
          }));

          console.log('gg', messageList);

          this.setState({
            messages: messageList,
            loading: false,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ messages: null, loading: false });
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:You might wanna take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794212/324977 for support on native array operations on firestore

That's because array is basically not really supported in Firebase.

> Firebase's Array Support
>   Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.

```
// we send this
['hello', 'world']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

Reference: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: how about the new firestore?

Comment: I've attached a link in the answer for firestore support