# Firestore push item to nested Array

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have Database like this
[image]

now I need to push items to directors array.

I tried this code

```
Firestore()
    .collection('notices')
    .doc(item.id)
    .set({readBy: {directors: [user.id]}}, {merge: true});
```

but it replace the existing items in directors array.

How to push items to directors array without replacing existing items ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757614/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-with-firestore)

Comment: No that is not.  That is Array of objects. my one is object of arrays

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [arrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) function for this:

```
Firestore()
.collection('notices')
.doc(item.id)
.set({readBy: {directors: FieldValue.arrayUnion([user.id])}}, {merge: true});
```