# Firebase Firestore: Merge a new array into an array stored in a document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

here is what I am trying to do:

1. There is an array k, stored under 'posts' index under the below document:

   ```
   k=['a','b',c']

   firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(uid)
   ```
2. Merge the below array to the existing array:

   ```
   k=['c','d']
   result=['a','b','c','d','e']
   ```

Is there a built-in syntax to do this in Firestore? I tried arrayUnion() method, like below, but it seems that it can insert a single element, not an actual array:

```
   firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(uid).update({
        posts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(k)
   })
```

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `SetOptions.merge` might help in you're case add it in the update field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757614/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-with-firestore)

Answer (score 1):

You try some like this

```
firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(uid).set({k: this.k}, {merge: true})
```

set with merge: true, if document or field in document exist is updated if not is created

Answer (score 0):

There is a breaking change in the Firebase Firestore you have to use the new way to set the merge key. I am doing this in dart as follows you can try this way hope it will work for you

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('ABC')
        .doc({uid})
        .set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```