# How to update specific object value in Firestore array

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a Vue application with Firebase.

My firestore structure
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgI5r.png)

I want to update all field of Id: 5

My code

```
import * as fb from '../firebase';
const DOC_ID = "xyz";

fb.db.collection("orders").doc(DOC_ID).update({
    regions: fb.db.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ Id: 5, Name: "newName", Mail: "new@email.com", ContactNo: 
"100000000" })
});
```

But I am getting error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined
```

I've tried this solutions but nothing work for me

[How to update an "array of objects" with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757614/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-with-firestore)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: In most implementations, the array union lives under `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion`. What is `fb.db` in your code?

Comment: Yes thanks, It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is suggesting that `fb.db.FieldValue` is undefined. That's why you're getting that TypeError.

In the official docs, the arrayUnion function can be accessed by this path: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion`

However, you're importing firebase from a local file `../firebase`.

We need to know the content of that file, in order to understand why your `firebase.db.FieldValue` is undefined. Maybe you're not exporting it correctly in the ../firebase file.

It's likely that your `..firebase` file is exporting the result of the `firebase.firestore()`. However, the FieldValue property is not accessed from this object.

Example:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue // This is correct
firebase.firestore().fieldvalue // This is incorrect
```

I think your `fb.db` is the result of a `firebase.firestore()`, and not the result of `firebase.firestore`

Comment: Sonikro was right. This is the correct one firebase.firestore.FieldValue