# Firestore arrayUnion() arrayRemove() links inside documentation not works

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

Visual Studio Code is not showing me links inside hints/snippet of some functions from Firestore. I don't know, is it because of some mistake in documentation or with my Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Inside documentation, those links are written like this:

```js
/**
 * Returns a special value that can be used with {@link @firebase/firestore/lite#(setDoc:1)} or {@link
 * @firebase/firestore/lite#(updateDoc:1)} that ...
```

My Visual Studio Code not reads them correct, or they are not correct ?

Also, above `arrayRemove()` function, there is missing a link:

```js
/**
 * Returns a special value that can be used with {@link (setDoc:1)} or {@link
 * updateDoc:1} that
```

File inside GitHub library is in: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/691292b8d576ce716ccc47af26cced9e700a278a/packages/firestore/src/lite-api/field_value_impl.ts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it's a documentation and link should look like this `{@link @firestore/lite#(setDoc:1)}` instead of like this `{@link @firebase/firestore/lite#(setDoc:1)}`. Those functions are exported from file `@firestore/lite` not `@firebase/firestore/lite`.

Comment: Good to hear you find the likely cause Mises. It might be best to file an issue on the Github repo, or even better: a PR that fixes it. :)